# MailItem.Reply() doesn't reply inline

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to be able to reply to an email inline, from within my program, but calling the reply function seems to only fill in the To: and Subject: field for me. I can't seem to find anything online about it and it doesn't seem to have an overload that turns on inline replies.

I found that each MailItem has a Conversation so I'm wondering if I have to manually do the inline reply? (I would really like to avoid that, it would be a pain to iterate through a conversation, some of ours can be hundreds of emails long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this code helped make this happen;

```
Document oldDoc = itemToReplyTo.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Document newDoc = newMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;

if (oldDoc != null)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection oldSelect = oldDoc.Windows[1].Selection;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection newSelect = newDoc.Windows[1].Selection;

    oldSelect.Find.Execute("From:");
    oldSelect.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
    oldSelect.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdStory, 1);
    oldSelect.Copy();

    newSelect.Move(WdUnits.wdStory, 1);
    newSelect.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard();
    newSelect.Paste();
    newSelect.Move(WdUnits.wdStory, -1);
    newSelect.InsertAfter("Reply Text here");
    newSelect.Find.ClearFormatting();
    newSelect.Find.Execute(mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it worked for me using Outlook 2010.

```
                        Outlook.MailItem reply1 = mailItem.Reply();                           
                        //prepend text to email
                        reply1.HTMLBody = "<html><body><strong>Test Body</strong><p><p></body></html>" + reply1.HTMLBody;
                        reply1.Display(false); //display message or .Send() to send
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the newer version of Outlook makes things much nicer/easier for developers.